# Difference between aws-sdk vs @aws-sdk

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

There two different nodejs sdk libraries that I have encountered: [`aws-sdk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk) and a [set of libaries under `@aws-sdk/`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html). What's the difference between the two, and which one should I use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk) ([github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js)) is for version 2.x

@aws-sdk modular packages ([github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3)) are for version 3.x

For a list of differences, check out the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html#welcome_whats_new_v3).